# How to add C# 11 required modifier to every property in my source without manual editing?

Tags: c#, properties, ide, refactoring, required

Now that C# 11 is out and the `required` modifier finally made it into the language, I would like to add this modifier to every property I own in all of my codebases (just about).

Editing the `.cs` files manually sounds like fun (not).

Is there a refactoring offered by some IDE or other tool that can do this automatically?

I have Visual Studio 2022 Pro, but would happily plunk down for another tool if I need it to get this job done.

Answer (score 0):

I Think Best Tools To Do This Work Is [JetBrains Resharper](https://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/)

Comment: I'm not seeing this particular refactor: https://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/whatsnew/#c-11  Maybe it's too early, and tools will add this in 2023.